# How to declare AR insert in polymorphic associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this code:

*model/agent.rb*

```
class Agent < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :user, :as => :profile
end
```

*model/default.rb*

```
class Default < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :user, :as => :profile
end
```

*model/user.rb*

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :profile, :polymorphic => true
end
```

*example.rb*

```
a = Agent.new
a.phone = '0000000'
a.status = 'xis'

u = User.new
u.name = 'Name'
u.email = 'email@email.com'
u.password = 'new123'
u.profile = agent
u.save!
```

This is the only way to write this code?

What better way to insert record in a polymorphic relationship? 
I can only have a `Agent.new`?

How to write updates statements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really an answer, but...

You can make the creation inline if it's more desirable

```
u.profile = Agent.new phone: '0000000', status: 'xis'
```

To update attributes inline

```
u.profile.update_attributes phone: '0000000'
```

Unfortunately, for polymorphic relationship, the `build_other` method doesn't exist as this would be the preferred way in non-polymorphic relationships for inserting associations on the fly.

See

> Auto-generated methods

in:
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html